# coalesce does not reduce my number of output files

Tags: output, apache-spark, avro, coalesce, rdd

I have a spark job which manages a `RDD[SpecificRecordBase]`, on a `HDFS`.

My problem is that it generates a lot of files, including 95% of empty avro files.
I tried to use coalesce to reduce my number of partitions on my RDD, and so the number of my output files, but it has no effect.

```
 def write(data: RDD[SpecificRecordBase]) = {
   data.coalesce(1, false)    //has no effect
   val conf = new Configuration()
   val job = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job(conf)

   AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, schema)
   val pair = new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
   pair.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
     outputAvroDataPath,
     classOf[AvroKey[SpecificRecordBase]],
     classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
     classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[SpecificRecordBase]],
     job.getConfiguration)
}
```

I suppose something is lost between `rdd` partition configuration and `HDFS` partition, and maybe `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` does not take it into account, but I'm not sure of it.

Have I missed something ?

Could somebody explain what really appends when calling `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` according to rdd partitionning ?

Comment: Are you sure you're outputting the `data` RDD? I don't see it from your code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line of code :

Comment: Can you add it, please?

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot a line of code : `val rdd = data.map(t => (new AvroKey(t), org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable.get))` in this sample, and yes I should apply coalesce on rdd val and not on data ! Then, coalesce returns a new RDD instead updating the current one, so it should be : `val rdd = data.map(t => (new AvroKey(t), org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable.get)).coalesce(1, false)` My mistake... thank you for this code review :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question thanks to @0x0FFF, the correct code should be :

```
    def write(data: RDD[SpecificRecordBase]) = {
           val rdd = data.map(t => (new AvroKey(t), org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable.get))
           val rdd1Partition = rdd.coalesce(1, false)  //change nb of partitions to 1

           val conf = new Configuration()
           val job = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job(conf)

           AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, schema)
           val pair = new PairRDDFunctions(rdd1Partition) //so only one file will be in output
           pair.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
             outputAvroDataPath,
             classOf[AvroKey[SpecificRecordBase]],
             classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
             classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[SpecificRecordBase]],
             job.getConfiguration)
        }
```

Thank you again !

Comment: To clarify on change:
Seb used the new rdd(rdd1Partition) created after using coalesce(). As if kept using the old rdd variable(rdd), it will not include the coalesce in lineage while executing.